# Android: BitmapFactory changes dimensions of image when decoding from ByteArray

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am converting an android Image captured in my application to a bitmap. I am doing this by getting the image buffer from the pixel plane of the image and then using BitMapFactory to decode it into a Bitmap. However, doing so seems to change the resolution of the Image from 1920 x 1440 to 1800 x 1600, cropping out the top and bottom of the image in the process. The code for the method is shown here.

```
`protected void getImageFromBuffer(ImageReader reader){
    Image image = null;
    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();

    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    System.out.println("Getting Image Ready");


    synchronized (this){
        image_to_upload = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
        buffer.get(image_to_upload);

        Bitmap storedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_to_upload, 0, image_to_upload.length, null);

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(jpegOrientation);  // angle is the desired angle you wish to rotate
        storedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(storedBitmap, 0, 0, storedBitmap.getWidth(), storedBitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        storedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,70, byteArrayOutputStream);
        image_to_upload = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        image_ready = true;
        System.out.println("Image Ready");
    }

}`
```

Debugging shows that the height and width of the Image are correct before the buffer is converted to a bitmap, but the bitmap dimensions are wrong immediately after decodeByteArray. Can anyone suggest why this may be? I have checked the dimensions before applying the matrix transformation.

EDIT: To add further details, I have tried using BitmapFactory.Options() to disable scaling or to set the target density and neither have any impact on the resulting Bitmap, it is always size 1800 x 1600.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get your desired result if you comment the line `mat.postRotate(jpegOrientation);` right? Use `Matrix#postScale()` then. See examples [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.graphics.Matrix&method=postScale).

Comment: @Darkman the aspect ratio is wrong even before the rotation is applied, I've checked the values before and after. The height and width of storedBitmap are 1600 x 1800 rather than 1920 x 1440. I'm not sure that scaling the image will help as parts of the image are being cropped out by all appearances.

Comment: I think the problem because you get the width and height after matrix manipulations. Try to store them in their own variable.

Comment: @Darkman I'm checking the width and height before matrix manipulation. I tried removing the line as you suggested and the same thing happens.

Comment: What's the source of the image?

Answer (score 2):

You can change some options that affects the result resolution of your bitmap by using the Options param to the decodeByteArray:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDensity =  DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH;//for example
    
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_to_upload, 0, image_to_upload.length, options);
```